# Java prefix TreeMap

Tags: java, collections, treemap

I have a lot of regexp rules more than(10k) and I would like to know which rules match for a particular string. I need collection where I can store this regex rules efficiently in order to detect which rules can be apply for a string.

I don't want to iterate all rules and decide which is good and which isn't. Are there any good algorithms for this problem?

Comment: Please be more specific.  Are you looking for a library suggestion?  In this case, I'm afraid the question will be off topic.  If you have any issues using regular expressions or implementing finite automatons, please explain those.  And for the “linear solutions aren't good” part, linear in what?  You'll have to look at least at your entire input.  And finally, what exactly do you want to compute?

Comment: As a matter of fact, all strings could match the regexp and that would take linear time at least.

Comment: Are you saying you want to test all 10k regexes against a single string without iterating through all 10k regexes? That sounds difficult. Do your regexes have any structural similarities that would allow you to discard a large number of them after testing a single one?

Comment: I would like to implement a hunspell word stemmer where is an affix file witch contains a lot of prefix and suffix rules. This rules are really similar but I must decide witch is good or not.  Finite State Transducers seems to be the best option. I would like to use this with regexp pattern matching but I don't know how can I do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I could resolve this problem, I created a regex rule container treeMap. I split regexpes into smaler parts where a regexpt part is appliable just for a single char, and that small regexp part would be a tree map node.

By using this treemap every match request costs just log(n).